# Can the existence of infinitely many even perfect numbers be settled by a diagonal argument?

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers

Say a (finite or not) sequence of strictly increasing positive integers $(u_{i})_{i\in I}$ is a 'Euclid sequence' if and only if the sum of reciprocals of all the $(u_i)$ equals $2$.

Now suppose we list all such sequences by increasing number of terms. The first sequence would be $(v_{1,i})=(1, 2, 3, 6)$, the second $(v_{2,i})=(1, 2, 3, 7, 42)$, the third $(v_{3,i})=(1, 2, 4, 7, 14, 28)$ and so on.

Consider now the sequence $(v_{i,i})=(1, 2, 4, 8,...)$. Is it a Euclid sequence?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: To answer your side-question: "a Euclid", not "an Euclid", since you pronounce "Euclid" as "Yuclid". By the way, I believe that it should be stated as "Euclid**ian**".

Comment: I'm not sure about all of the subtleties of language differences, but I think it should actually be *Euclidean* @barak manos. If it is generally spelled with an 'i' in your country's English, my apologies. :-) +$1$ for the question

Comment: @Clayton: It's not my question (and not my country's English), but thanks anyway :)

Comment: $(v_{2,i})$ isn't $(1,2,4,7,14,28)$ but rather (I believe) $(1,2,3,7,42)$.

Comment: @Wojowu: you're right. I propose the sequence with smallest sum of terms come first.

Comment: Also, your question title doesn't match with question body exactly - the latter doesn't mention perfect numbers.

Comment: Indeed. I kinda naively expected perfect numbers to be determined by the considered property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By numerical search I have found that the first few Euclid sequences are the following (ordered, per comment, first by length, second by sum of elements):

$$\begin{array}
&&1&2&3&6\\
&1&2&4&6&12\\
&1&2&3&10&15\\
&1&2&4&5&20\\
&1&2&3&9&18\\
&1&2&3&8&24\\
&1&2&3&7&42
\end{array}$$

and that these are all Euclid sequences up to 5 terms long.

We see from here that $(v_{i,i})$ starts with $(1,2,3,5,18,...)$ and it follows that it isn't Euclid sequence, since already $$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}>2$$

Comment: Ok, I haven't been restrictive enough. What if we add the condition $\omega(\prod_{j}v_{i,j})\leq 2$ for every finite Euclid sequence, where $\omega (n)$ is the cardinal of the set of primes dividing $n$, and $2\not\mid p$ implies the $p$-adic valuation of this product is at most half the number of terms?

Comment: @SylvainJulien If you are trying to make the only allowed sequences the sequences of divisors of (even) perfect numbers, then this still isn't restrictive enough - take a look at $(1,2,4,5,20)$.